# Electron browser window

Tags: electron

I have 2 `BrowserWindow` instances in my electron application, `mainWindow` and `secondaryWindow`. There is a button in `mainWindow` which when clicked should open `secondaryWindow`.

Now my issue is that I don't want to be able to click on anything in the `mainWindow` until the `secondaryWindow` is closed.

The closest I could get was to use `mainWindow.hide()` but this just completely hides the window, I want to still see the `mainWindow` while the `secondaryWindow` is active but it should be disabled / inactive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: make the child window a modal window. Example for  [window.open()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open) This will disable the parent window until the child window is closed.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to open a child window:

**1. from the main process:**

You can open a child window from the main process. This is for example useful for a custom window in the menu.

Here you can use the constructor to make it a child of `parent`. If the attribute `modal` is true, the parent window will not be accessible until the child window is closed.

```
function createChild(parent, html) {
  //creates modal window
  child = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 786,
    height: 847,
    parent: parent,
    modal: true,
    show: false
  });
  child.loadURL(html);
  child.webContents.openDevTools();
  child.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    child.show();
  });
}
```

**2. from the renderer process**

Now, we don't always want to send an event over the IPC to the main process just to open a child window, right?

We don't need to. We can use the `open` function on our window for that.

For example:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
     self.open(`file://${__dirname}/child.html`)
})
```

To make this window a child of your parent and modal, you can register an eventlistener on the parent window:

```
parent.webContents.on(
    "new-window",
    (event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) => {
      Object.assign(options, {
        parent: parent,
        modal: true
      });
    }
  );
```

With this, when `window.open()` is called on the parent window, it will open a modal child window.

**Example**

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let win;
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 800 });
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });

  win.webContents.on(
    "new-window",
    (event, url, frameName, disposition, options, additionalFeatures) => {
      Object.assign(options, {
        parent: win,
        modal: true
      });
    }
  );
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p>I am the parent, you can't touch me until you closed my child!</p>
    <button>Open child!</button>
    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector('button')
        button.addEventListener('click', e => {
            self.open(`file://${__dirname}/child.html`)
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

child.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    I'm the child!
</body>

</html>
```

### Update Electron 5 or higher

With electron 5 node integration was disabled in the renderer process by default for security reasons. Since this example uses `__dirname` (which is part of the node API) in the renderer process, we need to reintroduce it, because it is not available anymore. In this example I use a preload script for this purpose:

main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

let win;
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    },
  });
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null;
  });

  win.webContents.on(
    "new-window",
    (_event, _url, _frameName, _disposition, options, _additionalFeatures) => {
      Object.assign(options, {
        parent: win,
        modal: true,
      });
    }
  );
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow).catch(console.error);
```

preload.js

```js
window.__dirname = __dirname;
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>I am the parent, you can't touch me until you closed my child!</p>
    <button>Open child!</button>
    <script>
      const button = document.querySelector("button");
      button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        self.open(`file://${__dirname}/child.html`);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

child.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    I'm the child!
  </body>
</html>
```