# BrowserWindow Not a Constructor or Undefined - Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying out Electron on my MacBook for the first time because I want an environment I can code a desktop application in. I was a programmer before I retired and used various languages but not much javascript.

I'm going through the online tutorials to try to create a little app that just opens another window.  I have the main.js, index.js and index.html files set up.  I'm struggling with a couple of errors and I think they have to do with the 'remote' call.

In index.js when I include:

`const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow`

When main.js loads index.html I get the error:

`index.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of undefined at index.js:3`

When I take out 'remote' there is no error when main.js loads index.html, but when I try to use a button to open another window, I get this error:

`index.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:10) (anonymous) @ index.js:10`

I've spent a couple of days reading online and I'm not able to figure this out. I am running electron on a MacBook.  I would love some help on this.  I've been reading about remote and rendering etc but I'm not sure what is happening exactly.  Thanks!

Here are my files
main.js

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
//require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 800,
     height: 600,
     webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    })

   // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile('src/index.html')
    
   // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
  }

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/add.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="price-container">
          <p class="subtext">Current BTC USD</p>
          <h1 id="price">$9,503.21</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="goal-container">
          <p><img src="../assets/images/up.svg"><span id="targetPrice">Choose a Target Price</span></p>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
          <button id="notifyBtn">Notify me when..</button>
      </div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
//const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const notifyBtn = document.getElementById('notifyBtn')

notifyBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'add.html')
    let win = new BrowserWindow(
          {
            width: 400, height: 200,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true
            }
          }
        )
    win.on('close', function () { win = null })
    win.loadURL(modalPath)
    win.show()
  })
```

Comment: `const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote` – but be aware the `remote` is [deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#deprecated-remote-module)  in Electron 12

Comment: ```webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true, enableRemoteModule: true }```

Comment: you can't use the remote module unless the `enableRemoveModule` is true. This is false as default from v10

Comment: okay so ya'll are saying I should not use remote, which is fine with me.  When I take it out, though, I still get the error with the button press.

Comment: Electron has 2 different processes - the main process where you can use the node API without restriction - and the renderer process which does have the browser API but is restricted regarding the node API. The bridge between those processes is the IPC.  While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458487/4945892) answer is about how to open a modal window - it still should give you an idea how to open a child window from both main and renderer process - just ignore the modal part :)

Comment: I added an example that should work with electron 5 or higher to the bottom of that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MacBook too and I figured out how to open a new `BrowserWindow` when clicking on a button. You have to use the **IPC** from electron. In your .html when you have the button put a simple script at the end of the file as follows:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <button id=open>Open</button>
  
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const electron = require('electron');
  const { ipcRenderer } = electron;

  document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', event => {
    ipcRenderer.send('main:add');
  });
</script>
```

then in your electron main file (for me it was an `index.js` file) put the following:

```
let addWindow;

ipcMain.on('main:add', event => {
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  });
  addWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  addWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  addWindow.on('closed', () => {
    addWindow = null;
  });
});
```

and of course you have to define your `.html` file you want to open in  a new window. (for me this is an `index.html`).

Feel free to include the JS into your html from a separate file. I put it inside the html to keep things simpler.

If you want to send back information use `yourWindowNameInElectron.webContents.send('eventName')` in the electron main file and `ipcRenderer.on('eventName')` in your html. Note that the event in the electron must be the same as the event name in the html.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I have discovered Quasar and have been using it instead of Electron by itself.  My application will be desktop so have an Electron base with Quasar/Vue.